# Protractor: How to locate element if only image path is given

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, coffeescript, protractor

i want to check button is working or not, but the button only has image path given. so how can i locate this element.There is no class or id given.

```
<img alt="App Store" src="/assets/ap-store-button-f07ba2aa12bbdb0f4830b8a0f12f007a08151bd490498031e6b61092f51f9c56.png">
```

Comment: Am I the only person, who does not understand the problem?

Comment: i have two buttons with same image path    " <img alt="App Store" src="/assets/ap-store-button-f07ba2aa12bbdb0f4830b8a0f12f007a08151bd490498031e6b61092f51f9c56.png">  "...i have used <img alt="App Store">  .but it only works for one button. what about the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using cssSelector:

```
by.css('img[alt="App Store"]')
```

or

```
by.css('img[src="/assets/ap-store-button-f07ba2aa12bbdb0f4830b8a0f12f007a08151bd490498031e6b61092f51f9c56.png"]')
```

Comment: if there are two buttons with the same path, then how can we check both links? one is in header and second is in footer

Comment: try using the following: `element.all(locator).get(index);`..you can find more alternatives here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/locators

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element by the alt tag.

```
[alt="App Store"]
```

Comment: actually am new . please elaborate

Comment: How do you locate if the image has class or id?

Comment: element(By.id('someID')).click()

Comment: if there are two buttons with the same path, then how can we check both links? one is in header and second is in footer

Answer (score 0):

When you have two elements on the page with same html then you can try to get all and iterate through it.

```
var e = element.all(by.css("img[alt=App Store]"));
for (i=0; i<e.length; i++) {
e.get(i).click();
}
```

If you need to click the first one then you can try

```
e.first().click();
```

Comment: and am using coffeescript to write test cases

Comment: @SaqibTanvir I think you may need to define the variable in separate line like   `var e;  e = element.all(by.css("img[alt=App Store]"));`

Comment: does anybody knows how can we use loop statement in protractor in cofeescript?

Comment: how can we make protractor to press Enter Key?